# How to generate a tz4 (BLS-MinPk key pair) address

Tags: account, cryptography

I'd like to generate a Tezos tz4 (BLS sig) address.

What do I need to know about this curve and what is a tool (preferably CLI) I can use to create a tz4 address for myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `octez-client`:

```
$ octez-client gen keys <account alias> --sig bls
```